# Mathematica - Searching a clever way to do a computation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematica

I am solving this differential equation using Mathematica
$$x ~y''(x)+\alpha ~ y'(x)+\frac{1-3\mu (x)}{(1-x) x}=0$$
where $\mu(x)$ is a polynomial:
$$\mu (x)=a+b\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+c\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^2+d\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^3+e\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^4+f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^5$$

The problem comes here. If I solve it directly (just replacing the expression of $\mu(x)$ I get a specific solution (really long and complex). Then I though about splitting the  polynomial , that is:
$$x ~y''(x)+\alpha ~ y'(x)+\frac{1-3(a+b\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right))}{(1-x) x}+\frac{-3c(\frac{1}{1-x})^2}{(1-x) x}+\frac{-3d\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^3}{(1-x) x}+\frac{-3e\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^4}{(1-x) x}+\frac{-3f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^5}{(1-x) x}=0$$
I didn't think a lot if this was going to work and I solved the following:
$$x ~y''(x)+\alpha ~ y'(x)+\frac{1-3(a+b\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right))}{(1-x) x}=0$$
$$x ~y''(x)+\alpha ~ y'(x)+\frac{-3c\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^2}{(1-x) x}=0$$
$$x ~y''(x)+\alpha ~ y'(x)+\frac{-3d\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^3}{(1-x) x}=0$$
$$x ~y''(x)+\alpha ~ y'(x)+\frac{-3e\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^4}{(1-x) x}=0$$
$$x ~y''(x)+\alpha ~ y'(x)+\frac{-3f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^5}{(1-x) x}=0$$
wondering that the sum of my solutions would be the same as the total solution computed at the beginning. Now I see this makes no sense (right?). They don't have to be the same (a funny thing is that if a plot both solutions it seems like they have the same shape but are just shifted in the Y axis). My question is, Is there any way of taking advantage of this splitting in order to find a simpler result?

Thank you!

(I editted the formula of $\mu(x)$, it was not correct)

Comment: Your equation is linear so the solution should definitely be expressible as a linear combination of the partial solutions when splitting up your polynomial. You have a second order equation so you are looking for two linearly independent solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Given a non homogeneous linear differential equation
$$
a_2(x)y''+a_1(x)y'+a_0(x)y=b(x)
$$
then the general integral is a linear combination of two independent solution of the associated homogeneous equation, say $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$, plus a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation, say $y_p(x)$:
$$
y(x;c_1,c_2)=c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)+y_p(x)
$$
When the term $b(x)$ is a sum of two (or more) terms, say $b(x)=b_1(x)+b_2(x)$, then it is easy to see that $y_p(x)=y_{p,1}(x)+y_{p,2}(x)$ is a solution of the non-homogeneous equation, where $y_{p,1}(x)$ is a particular solution taking into account only $b_1(x)$, and similarly for $y_{p,2}(x)$.

So yes, it is possible to split the term $b(x)$ in a sum, solve the reduced equations then sum the results, but the initial conditions, required to determine the constant $c_1$, $c_2$ must be applied to the full solution.

Comment: I see! Thank you both. Then it was fine. The thing I don't understand now is the following.  First of all, I want to remark that I'm just interested in the particular solution of my equation, so I forget about c1,c2 and focuse of $y_p$. When I find  $y_p$ for the full equation, two constants appear and I decide to set them to zero. The same happens when I compute $y_{p,1}$ ,$y_{p,2}$ ,$y_{p,3}$ ,$y_{p,4}$ ,$y_{p,5}$ and I set all the integration constants also to zero. The problem is, why $$y_p\neq y_{p,1} +y_{p,2} +y_{p,3} +y_{p,4} +y_{p,5}$$ $$$$

Comment: @lailola: the particular solution is not unique, so what you are guaranteed is that both member of this inequality are solutions of the non-homogeneous equation. Here resides the necessity to setup a Cauchy problem choosing the initial condition. In general you do not want to take a random solution setting $c_1,c_2=0$, but a specific solution with respect to some condition.

Comment: That's true. They both shoud satisfy the equation but that doesn't mean that they have to be equal. I thought that setting the same pair of conditions (c[1]=0,c[2]=0) for every equation would give me the same result. I don't see how can I force $y_p\neq y_{p,1} +y_{p,2} +y_{p,3} +y_{p,4} +y_{p,5}$ to be equal to the particular solution of the full equation.